# how to get old value in jQuery UI slider change method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

how can i set previous value is their anything , i dont want to add custom code to store the old data etc.

```
$('#rating').slider({
    value: 10,
    range: "min",              
    max: 10,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if(ui.value<7) {
            if(confirm('Are you sure ')){                           
                //functioality
            }else{
                //set it to previous value not fix 10
                $('#'+this.id).slider('value',10);
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**place a hidden field in your form**

```
<input type="hidden" id="HDrating">
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#rating').slider({
    value: 10,
    range: "min",              
    max: 10,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if(ui.value<7) {
            if(confirm('Are you sure ')){                           
                //functioality
                //Store selected value in hidden field
                $("#HDrating").val(ui.value);
            }else{
                //set hidden field value in rating field
                $('#'+this.id).slider('value',$("#HDrating").val());
            }
        }else{
            $("#HDrating").val(ui.value);
        }
    },
});
```